# implement change password function symfony 2 with FOS

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I want to implement password change functionality with FOS but I don't know how to do it.

I started by creating a form with two attributes (old password and new password (repeated).

```
class ChangePasswordType extends UtilisateurType{ 

/**
 * @SecurityAssert\UserPassword(
 *     message = "pswd ko"
 * )
 */
protected $oldPassword;

/**
 * @Assert\Length(
 *     min = 7,
 *     max = 255,
 *     minMessage = "pswd too short"
 *     maxMessage = "pswd too long" 
 * )
 */
protected $newPassword;

protected $user;


public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('old', 'password', array('label' => 'Mot de passe actuel','attr' => array('placeholder' => 'Sasir votre mot de passe actuel','class' =>'form-control')));
    $builder->add('newPassword', 'repeated', array(
            'type' => 'password',
            'invalid_message' => ' Les deux mots de passe ne sont pas identiques  .',
            'required' => true,
            'first_options'  => array('label' => 'Nouveau mot de passe', 'attr' => array('placeholder' => 'Sasir un nouveau mot de passe','class' =>'form-control')),
            'second_options' => array('label' => 'Vérification', 'attr' => array('placeholder' => 'Vérification','class' =>'form-control')),
    ));
}


/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getName()
{
    return 'Mybundle_changePassword';
}
```

In my controller, I create the form like this:

```
        $form = $this->createForm(new ChangePasswordType(), null, array(
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('fos_user_change_password'),
            'method' => 'POST',
    ));
```

In my twig, I have this form and a submit button (action: `changePasswordAction` of `ChangePasswordController` in FOS), but it doesn't work.

```
                            {{ form_start(formChangerPswd) }}
                                {{ form_widget(formChangerPswd) }}
                                    <div class="box-footer">
                                        <input type="submit" value="Modify pswd" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" formnovalidate="formnovalidate"/>
                                    </div><!-- /.box-footer -->
                                {{ form_end(formChangerPswd) }}
```

I have this **error** :

> Cannot read index "oldPassword" from object of type "MyBundle\Entity\User" because it doesn't implement \ArrayAccess.

Is it the best way to implement this function ?
Can somebody help me, please?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Did you notice that the bundle already ships with a form type for this feature?

Comment: I'm trying to implement a change password function.

Comment: That doesn't explain why you build the form type yourself while reusing the rest of the feature that is already provided by FOSUserBundle.

Comment: Can you explain to me just the method to implement this function using the form and controller of fos, please ?

Comment: You simply need to add a link to the `fos_user_change_password` route.

Comment: I have to generate a change password form in a controller, and display it in a view ?

Comment: Why do you need to create a new password? The user enters it in the form.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using FOSUser bundle you don't need to create a custom password change logic, all you need to do is go to the twig template where you want to instantiate the password change and add this

```
<a href="{{ path('fos_user_change_password') }}">Change Password</a>
```

the above code is the route to the change password process, it makes a call to the fosUser changepassword controller .

NOTE: If you are setting up the fosUser bundle  newly you would need to override the built in template and customize it to have the theme of your site. If you don't know how to do that you can visit this site it will give you a good startup
http://www.sitepoint.com/basic-user-management-in-symfony2-with-fosuserbundle/

But

> **If you want to handle the change password process from your custom controller**

```
    namespace FOS\UserBundle\Controller;

   use FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserEvents;
   use FOS\UserBundle\Event\FormEvent;
   use FOS\UserBundle\Event\FilterUserResponseEvent;
   use FOS\UserBundle\Event\GetResponseUserEvent;
   use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface;
   use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
   use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
   use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
   use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException;

    /**
     * your custom Controller managing the password change
     *
     * 
     */
  class ProfileController extends Controller
     {
     /**
      * Change user password
       */
      public function changePasswordAction(Request $request)
       {
    $user = $this->getUser();



    //dispatch the appropriate events

    /** @var $dispatcher \Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface */
    $dispatcher = $this->get('event_dispatcher');

    $event = new GetResponseUserEvent($user, $request);
    $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::CHANGE_PASSWORD_INITIALIZE,            $event);

    if (null !== $event->getResponse()) {
        return $event->getResponse();
    }


 /**
  * this is where you start the initialization of the form to you use
  */

    /** @var $formFactory \FOS\UserBundle\Form\Factory\FactoryInterface           */
    $formFactory = $this->get('fos_user.change_password.form.factory');

    $form = $formFactory->createForm();
      //pass in the user data
    $form->setData($user);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        /** @var $userManager \FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface */
        $userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');

        $event = new FormEvent($form, $request);
        $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::CHANGE_PASSWORD_SUCCESS, $event);

        $userManager->updateUser($user);

        if (null === $response = $event->getResponse()) {
            //here you set the url to go to after changing the password
              //for example i am redirecting back to the page  that triggered the change password process
            $url = $this->generateUrl('showProfileAccount');
            $response = new RedirectResponse($url);
        }

        $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::CHANGE_PASSWORD_COMPLETED, new FilterUserResponseEvent($user, $request, $response));

        return $response;
    }

    return $this->render('FOSUserBundle:ChangePassword:changePassword.html.twig', array(
       //note remove this comment. pass the form to template
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ));
}
}
```

Template

```
    {{ form_start(form) }}
     {{ form_widget(form) }}
     <div>
    <input type="submit" value="{{ 'change_password.submit'|trans }}" />
     </div>
  {{ form_end(form) }}
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer, but it doesn't answer my question. I have a user profile view, and I want to integrate the change password form in this view. So, I have to initialize the form in the controller which render the profil view ?

Comment: @peace wait let me edit my answer to show you how to initialize the change password process from your custom controller

Comment: Thnk's @Akoh, you modified it or not yet ?

Comment: @peace yes i have modified it since, if it has not taken effect at your end let me know so i can post the answer again

Comment: Can you post the answer again please ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using FOSUser bundle you don't need to create a custom password change logic, all you need to do is go to the twig template where you want to instantiate the password change and add this

```
<a href="{{ path('fos_user_change_password') }}">Change Password</a>
```

the above code is the route to the change password process, it makes a call to the fosUser changepassword controller .

NOTE: If you are setting up the fosUser bundle  newly you would need to override the built in template and customize it to have the theme of your site. If you don't know how to do that you can visit this site it will give you a good startup
http://www.sitepoint.com/basic-user-management-in-symfony2-with-fosuserbundle/

**But if you must handle the process yourself the procedure below is how to go about it**

> **If you want to handle the change password process from your custom controller**

```
    namespace FOS\UserBundle\Controller;

   use FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserEvents;
   use FOS\UserBundle\Event\FormEvent;
   use FOS\UserBundle\Event\FilterUserResponseEvent;
   use FOS\UserBundle\Event\GetResponseUserEvent;
   use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface;
   use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
   use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
   use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
   use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException;

    /**
     * your custom Controller managing the password change
     *
     * 
     */
  class ProfileController extends Controller
     {
     /**
      * Change user password
       */
      public function changePasswordAction(Request $request)
       {
    $user = $this->getUser();



    //dispatch the appropriate events

    /** @var $dispatcher \Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface */
    $dispatcher = $this->get('event_dispatcher');

    $event = new GetResponseUserEvent($user, $request);
    $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::CHANGE_PASSWORD_INITIALIZE,            $event);

    if (null !== $event->getResponse()) {
        return $event->getResponse();
    }


 /**
  * this is where you start the initialization of the form to you use
  */

    /** @var $formFactory \FOS\UserBundle\Form\Factory\FactoryInterface           */
    $formFactory = $this->get('fos_user.change_password.form.factory');

    $form = $formFactory->createForm();
      //pass in the user data
    $form->setData($user);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        /** @var $userManager \FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface */
        $userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');

        $event = new FormEvent($form, $request);
        $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::CHANGE_PASSWORD_SUCCESS, $event);

        $userManager->updateUser($user);

        if (null === $response = $event->getResponse()) {
            //here you set the url to go to after changing the password
              //for example i am redirecting back to the page  that triggered the change password process
            $url = $this->generateUrl('showProfileAccount');
            $response = new RedirectResponse($url);
        }

        $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::CHANGE_PASSWORD_COMPLETED, new FilterUserResponseEvent($user, $request, $response));

        return $response;
    }

    return $this->render('FOSUserBundle:ChangePassword:changePassword.html.twig', array(
       //note remove this comment. pass the form to template
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ));
}
}
```

Template

```
    {{ form_start(form) }}
     {{ form_widget(form) }}
     <div>
    <input type="submit" value="{{ 'change_password.submit'|trans }}" />
     </div>
  {{ form_end(form) }}
```